# Отношения и взаимоотношения: в чем разница?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

"У них хорошие отношения" и "у них хорошие взаимоотношения". Есть ли разница между этими понятиями и, если да, то в чем она?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У них хорошие отношения с кем? Без этого уточнения (в самом предложении либо в общем контексте) фраза звучит не совсем понятно. Слово "взаимоотношение" как раз и является подобным уточнением. У них хорошие отношения именно друг с другом, а не с соседями, родственникам, коллегами или ещё кем-то.

Answer (score 0):

по мне разница есть в том.отношения это когда по разному относится друг к другу.один презирает дпругой любит.так и говорят у нас не складываются отношения.а взаимоотношения это *отдавать-получать*.или как гооврится *сегодня ты мне.завтра я тебе*

Comment: Сильно. Я один ничего не понял?

Comment: Если перевести с птичьего: отличие отношений от взаимоотношений — в прохладности и даже в неприязни к человеку. В отдельных случаях, эта неровность в отношениях означает безответное чувство, называемое в народе любовью.

Answer (score 0):

Их взаимоотношения. У них отношения. Слова штучны и не могут так легко, без правки текста, замещать другие.